# SQL Server query to add a column based on value of another column

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that select a list of DATETIME values and I would like to add to this selection a column that is populated based on the value of DATETIME column

Example for every value that is between 19:00 and 23:00 the value in the new column should be 2

Value DATETIME    2022-04-05 22:25:39.083
Value NEW COLUMN  2

My goal is to only select this new value, I cannot make modifications to the exiting table

It is something that can be managed by SQL Server?
Thanks

I don't know how to create new columns and if is possible to use like IF statement in SQL

Comment: `CASE WHEN CONVERT(time(0),YourColumn) BETWEEN '19:00:00' AND '23:00:00' THEN 2 END`?

Comment: Your statement 'only select this new value' isn't clear.  Do you mean you want to select only rows that meet that criteria?  If so - then you can use WHERE cast(YourColumn As time(0)) BETWEEN '19:00:00' AND '23:00:00'.

Answer (score 0):

first let's discuss how to provide example data. One of the better options is to define an object we can easily replicate, and then populate it with some data. In this case the datetime values don't matter, they just need to exist. Something like this will get us there:

```
DECLARE @dates TABLE (DateID INT IDENTITY, DateTime DATETIME)
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @dates) < 100
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @dates (DateTime) 
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,(ROUND(((96 - 1 -1) * RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY)) + 1), 0) - 1),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
END
```

All we're doing here is generating a random datetime in the next 96 hours and inserting it into our table variable.

Now on to your problem.
This is easily resolved by using the TIME data type. You can cast any DATETIME to a TIME. Then, you can simply compare it to a valid time range, using a case expression:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN CAST(DateTime AS TIME) BETWEEN '19:00' AND '23:00' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END AS NewColumn
  FROM @dates
 ORDER BY DateTime
```

```
DateID  DateTime                NewColumn
-----------------------------------------
81      2022-11-07 17:13:39.813 0
78      2022-11-07 18:13:39.813 0
22      2022-11-07 19:13:39.810 2
87      2022-11-07 19:13:39.813 2
95      2022-11-07 19:13:39.813 2
2       2022-11-08 01:13:39.807 0
98      2022-11-08 01:13:39.813 0
12      2022-11-08 04:13:39.807 0
...
19      2022-11-08 17:13:39.810 0
34      2022-11-08 19:13:39.810 2
56      2022-11-08 19:13:39.810 2
39      2022-11-08 19:13:39.810 2
66      2022-11-08 22:13:39.810 2
96      2022-11-08 22:13:39.813 2
90      2022-11-08 22:13:39.813 2
50      2022-11-08 23:13:39.810 0
5       2022-11-09 00:13:39.807 0
...
46      2022-11-11 09:13:39.810 0
6       2022-11-11 10:13:39.807 0
51      2022-11-11 11:13:39.810 0
```